# How hide form after submit in Angular2?

Tags: forms, angular, submit, hide

I have the form in Angular 2. After submit a want to hide this and show a message.

```
<div class="registration">
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="RegisterUser(registrationForm.value)" novalidate>
...
</form>
</div>
```

In Angular I do this use the code below:

```
<div class="registration" ng-hide="registrationForm.$submitted" >
<form name="registrationForm" ng-submit="RegisterUser()" novalidate>
...
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply bind to `toggle` variable and show/hide as per your requirements like this

```
<div class="message" *ngIf="formSubmit; else #theForm">Message here</div>
<div class="registration" #theForm>
    <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="RegisterUser(registrationForm.value); formSubmit = !formSubmit">
    ...
    </form>
</div>
```

or

```
<ng-template *ngIf="formSubmit; then #alreadySubmitted else #theForm"></ng-template>
<div class="message" #alreadySubmitted>
    Message here
</div>
<div class="registration" #theForm>
    <form [formGroup]="registrationForm"
      (ngSubmit)="RegisterUser(registrationForm.value); formSubmit = !formSubmit">
    ...
    </form>
</div>
```

PS: you can use `[hidden]` too for toggle view.

Comment: Also, you can use the `if else` syntax: `<div *ngIf="boolean; else ref>...</div>` and after the div, `<ng-template #ref>...</ng-template>`. You can also use a `div` instead of `ng-template`. This saves you repeating `ngIf` twice.

Comment: exactly well said. @GioraGuttsait if you want to edit my answer for better way you can , ill approve your edit.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use `*ngIf`:

```
<div class="registration" *ngIf="showForm">
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="RegisterUser(registrationForm.value);showForm=false;" novalidate>
...
</form>
</div>
```

and in your typescript initialize the variable:

```
showForm=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a template variable for the form and use the [submitted](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#submitted) member of `ngForm` directive

```
<form #form="ngForm" [hidden]="form.submitted">
    ...
</form>
```

But this will not work with `*ngIf` if memory saving is important in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
<div class="registration" [hidden]="submitted">
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="RegisterUser(registrationForm.value)" novalidate>
...
</form>
</div>
```

Your component ts file

```
RegisterUser(){
-----

submitted=true
}
```

Comment: It's useful to note that `*ngIf` is recommended over `[hidden]` in most cases since `[hidden]` keeps the object in DOM memory, but `*ngIf` destroys the DOM and frees memory.

Comment: It was given as another approach. And this approach is in the demo of official documentation on angular.io as well. It is upto the user what he needs to use based on the use case.

Comment: Didn't downvote you. I just wanted anyone who's not familiar to be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="registration" *ngIf="ifregistration"
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="RegisterUser(registrationForm.value)" novalidate>
</form>
</div>
```

In Typescript initialize the variable:

```
RegisterUser(f: NgForm) {
    if (f.valid) {
        var form_submitted = f.value
        this.loading = true;
        this.ifregistration = false;
    }
}
```